# Add users to production membershipprovider database through stored procedures?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, asp.net-membership

I am about to deploy a tiny asmx webservice to a production server, but I need to add a user to the `MembershipProvider` database (Oracle version).

I can't (won't) add any pages to this site, its just the webservice, and IT Admin won't let me add the WebAdmin tool (as per http://forums.asp.net/t/932674.aspx/1) so I need to be able to add users to the backing database somehow?

I can see there are SP's for this, but I am not sure what I need to call and with what parameters. e.g. the createuser sp has `UserName` and `UserId`... but it's not clear what each one is... and there doesn't appear to be anything for password???

Comment: I'm in a similar boat.  Some of the SPs *appear* to be slightly redundant.  I just ran aspnet_reqsql.exe v4.0.30319.17929 and it *looks* like aspnet_Membership_CreateUser may be an SP that we can take interest in.  When I look at the code for that SP, it *seems* to create a new user of specified name with specified password and then return a userId as output.

Comment: I ended up insalling and then deleting the web admin tool...not good.  So still VERY interested in knowing how to use the SP's independently.

Comment: I understand. I *seem* to have a solution that adds a user via SPs for *me* in T-SQL, but you seem to have indicated that you are using an Oracle version of the ASP.NET Membership Database.  Since you need an Oracle specific version, it is probably inappropriate for me to post my code as an answer.  On the other hand, if you are just curious as to what *seemed* to work for me in T-SQL, you can look at Step#1 of this file and send me your comments for improvement: https://usedcarlot.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#481087